# HTableDescriptor(table) in hbase is deprecated and alternative for that?

Tags: hadoop, hbase

> HTableDescriptor htd = new HTableDescriptor(table);

The above statement gives the **htable descriptor as deprecated**

I have searched so many places but unable to get alternative for this.... any help is appreciated

Comment: what is the data type of table in your example?

Comment: see my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53507343/3525886

Answer (score 3):

I guess you are using the constructor with a string parameter i.e. your argument variable 'table' is a string:

```
HTableDescriptor(String name); //Deprecated
```

You need to construct a table descriptor specifying a TableName object as:

```
HTableDescriptor(TableName name);
```

For further details related to TableName object, you can use this link:
https://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/TableName.html

Comment: HTableDescriptor htd = new HTableDescriptor(TableName.valueOf(table)); is the statement we need to use

Answer (score 2):

> HTableDescriptor As of release 2.0.0, this will be removed in HBase 3.0.0.
>
> - Use {@link TableDescriptorBuilder} to build {@link HTableDescriptor}.

```java
TableName tname = TableName.valueOf(fullTableName);
TableDescriptorBuilder tableDescBuilder = TableDescriptorBuilder.newBuilder(tname);
ColumnFamilyDescriptorBuilder columnDescBuilder = ColumnFamilyDescriptorBuilder
    .newBuilder(Bytes.toBytes(family))
    .setBlocksize(32 * 1024)
    .setCompressionType(Compression.Algorithm.SNAPPY)
    .setDataBlockEncoding(DataBlockEncoding.NONE);
tableDescBuilder.setColumnFamily(columnDescBuilder.build());
tableDescBuilder.build();
```